# Nginx location matching everything ending with favicon.ico

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

This is a static file server, and I am trying to match everything ending with `favicon.ico` so that I can serve the favicon from `/u/static`.

```
location ~* /favicon.ico {
    root /u/static;
}
```

It works for `static.domain.tld/favicon.ico`

But not for `static.domain.tld/x1/favicon.ico`, `static.domain.tld/x2/favicon.ico`

How can I catch all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx locates the path to the file by concatenating the value of `root` with the value of the URI, so in your example, the URI `/foo/favicon.ico` will be searched for at `/u/static/foo/favicon.ico`.

Use `try_files` to force Nginx to look for a single static file. For example:

```
location ~* /favicon\.ico$ {
    root /u/static;
    try_files /favicon.ico =404;
}
```

The `try_files` statement requires at least two parameters, but the `=404` will never be reached. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.